# In vue api composition should I use ref inside reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

In `reactive` in vue api composition, should I use ref or not? is it the same? reactive does what ref do?

```
const state = reactive({
  loading: ref(true)
});
```

or

```
const state = reactive({
  loading: true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do that.
You can just use `state.loading = something` and it's already reactive.

But please be aware of this.
`state.loading = ture/false` is reactive but
`state = { loading: true/false }` is not reactive and you can lose the reactive variable reference